# Python Dictionary combining by current expression

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
x = [{'policy': 'a-b-windows2007',  'starttime': '4', 'duration': '5'}, 
     {'policy': 'ab-server2012', 'starttime': '4', 'duration': '5'}, 
     {'policy': 'Aa-windows', 'starttime': '4', 'duration': '5'}]

y = [{'policy': 'Windws a-b-windows2007', 'total_hosts': '160'},
     {'policy': 'Windows ab-server2012', 'total_hosts': '170'},
     {'policy': 'Windows Aa-windows', 'total_hosts': '180'}]
```

I want to have one dict by combining x and y if policy in x = policy in y. I have created regex and I am struggling how to merge them

x and y are not the same length.

My attempt so far:

```
 for key in x:
     for keys in y:
         if key['policy'] == re.match('[0-9]+|\b[a-z-]+(\d)',keys['policy']):
             z.update(y)
```

Wanted output:

```
z=[{policy: 'a-b-windows2007',starttime: '4', duration: '5',total_hosts:'160'}, 
   {policy: 'ab-server2012',starttime: '4', duration: '5',total_hosts:'170'}, 
   {policy: 'Aa-windows',starttime: '4', duration: '5',total_hosts:'180'}]
```

Comment: What do you do if there is a policy in one that is not in the other?

Comment: What's your attempt so far?

Comment: @Rightleg see edit

Comment: @PatrickHaugh It's always existing policy.

Comment: @MooingRawr check out now. The think is that policy: 'Windows Aa' == policy: 'Aa'

Comment: a has no relation to Aa... "Aa" is equal to "Windows Aa", "a" is equal to "Windows a" @MooingRawr

Comment: @Maltesse Then your output doesn't match what you want: `{policy: 'a',starttime: '4', duration: '5',total_hosts:'160'}` why did this get an `'a' total_host` value?

Comment: What you want is called joining operation. Also, please describe better how policies should be compared. They're not equal, and, probably, contain mistypes. You have to look at pandas: code will be faster and more concise.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov I have edited the code, now it should be clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex wasn't working for me, here's a nested for loop solution assume t hat your `policy` follows: this format `<windows> <version_number>` we split the policy value and take the version_number to compare, you can easily convert it to a dict comprehension if you so wish too..

```
x = [{'policy': 'a-b-windows2007',  'starttime': '4', 'duration': '5'}, 
     {'policy': 'ab-server2012', 'starttime': '4', 'duration': '5'}, 
     {'policy': 'Aa-windows', 'starttime': '4', 'duration': '5'}]

y = [{'policy': 'Windows a-b-windows2007', 'total_hosts': '160'},
     {'policy': 'Windows ab-server2012', 'total_hosts': '170'},
     {'policy': 'Windows Aa-windows', 'total_hosts': '180'}]

for x_dict in x:
    for y_dict in y:
        if x_dict['policy'] == y_dict['policy'].split(' ')[1]:
            if "total_hosts" in x_dict:
                x_dict["total_hosts"].append(y_dict["total_hosts"])
            else:
                x_dict["total_hosts"] = y_dict["total_hosts"]

print(x)
```

Gives:

```
[{'starttime': '4', 'duration': '5', 'policy': 'a-b-windows2007', 'total_hosts': '160'}, 
{'starttime': '4', 'duration': '5', 'policy': 'ab-server2012', 'total_hosts': '170'}, 
{'starttime': '4', 'duration': '5', 'policy': 'Aa-windows', 'total_hosts': '180'}]
```

This solution updates the `x list` so if you want a new list without changing x, just make a copy of x to change called z and change the for loops where ever x is make it to z...

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Umm not it's not ? x is a list of dictionary objects..... and it matches your output, I really don't understand what you are asking now... @Maltesse

Comment: No, you are right, that was just my typo mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

`merge_dicts` is necessary evil from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987).

I assume that `Windws` is mistype. Otherwise, you have to specify join condition clearer.

Turning `y` into indexed dictionary yield good performance gain over nested for loops.

```
def merge_dicts(x, y):
    z = x.copy()
    z.update(y)
    return z

y_indexed = {e['policy']: e for e in y}
joined = [
    merge_dicts(y_indexed['Windows ' + e['policy']], e)
    for e in x]
```

Consider using pandas if you have lots of such `dict`s.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a regular expression in this particular case; but it's not hard to modify the code to include one.

You can do something similar to this:

```
l=[]
for xItem in x:
  for yItem in y:
    if yItem['policy'].endswith(xItem['policy']):
      tmpItem=xItem
      tmpItem['total_hosts'] = yItem['total_hosts']
      l.append(tmpItem)
```

A bit inefficient, but sorting the lists beforehand will help, but only if the lists a large enough for the sorting time to be amortized.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the lists are the same length and that every element in `x` has a corresponding element in `y`.

Sort the lists so the matching dictionaries share an index, then `zip` the two together. The use `itertools.chain` to feed them to the `dict` constructor.

```
import itertools
x.sort(key=lambda x: x['policy'])
y.sort(key=lambda x: x['policy'])
z = [dict(itertools.chain(a.items(), b.items())) for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

I think on more recent versions of python you can do `dict(**a, **b)`, but I'm using 3.3 on this computer so I can't be sure.

Another way of doing it would be to convert `y`, the list that has no duplicate policies, into a dictionary.

```
y_dict = {d['policy'].split()[-1]: d for d in y}
```

`.split()[-1]` will give us the last word of the policy entry.  Then we can go through x to build our new list.

```
z = []
for d in x:
    new_dict = {k:v for k,v in d.items()}
    new_dict.update({k:v for k, v in y_dict[d['policy']] if k != 'policy'})
    z.append(new_dict)
```

Comment: They are not the same size unfortunately. Each key has corresponding value.

Comment: Does every `x` have exactly one `y`?  Does every `y` have exactly one `x`?  Are there some policy values that have duplicates in both lists?

Comment: policy in dict x: compliance-smth
policy in dict y: Windows compliance-smth
They are the same if I am using expression result = re.match('[0-9]+|\b[a-z-]+(\d)', y['policy'])

Comment: So which policy do you want the end result to have?

Comment: Check the edit, I just explained better what it should be

Comment: Are there entries in `x` without corresponding entries in `y`, or entries in `y` without corresponding entries in `x`?

Comment: entries in x without corresponding entries in y. But the policies are the same so it should just copy the number of hosts

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `endswith` method is much simpler (and probably more robust) than a regex.

```
z = {}
for key in x:
    print(key['policy'])
    for keys in y:
        print(keys['policy'])
        if keys['policy'].endswith(key['policy']):
            kz = key.copy()  # copy to avoid any change in x
            kz['total_hosts'] = keys['total_hosts']
            z.append(kz)
```